# Automatically add class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>sf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sf</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

How can i make automatically add class red and green for TR with jQuery?

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/2Htwx/

Comment: `$('tr').addClass('red').addClass('green')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('tr:odd').addClass('red');
$('tr:even').addClass('green');​
```

Assuming you want every other row red or green, as per your JS-fiddle. Note that this is within each table, so you won't see red/green/red across ALL table rows.

If you want that, try this:

```
var oddFilter = function(index) {
     console.log(index);
  return (index % 2) == 1;
},
 evenFilter = function(index) {
     console.log(index);
  return (index % 2) == 0;
}

$('tr').filter(oddFilter).addClass('red').end()
       .filter(evenFilter).addClass('green');​
```

Note that `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` etc can still mess up the display, since that moves rows around the display.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need JavaScript to accomplish this 'table-striping' effect. Use of the CSS nth-child selector will do the trick

```
thead tr {
    background: green; /* Set all tr elements to green */
}

thead tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: red; /* Override the colour for just the even ones */
}
```

Note: This selector is not supported in older browsers. IE8 and down.

Further reading on CSS nth-child:

- http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Comment: selectivzr adds support for this selector to old versions of IE: http://selectivizr.com/

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var class = "";
     $("tr").each(function(idx, elem) {
        class = (idx % 2 == 0)?"red":"green";
        $(elem).addClass(class);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain "automatically"?
You mean at page ready event?

Maybe somthing like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#f00");
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#0f0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var trs = jQuery('tr');
trs.filter(':even').addClass('red');
trs.filter(':odd').addClass('green');
```

to not selecting two-times every tr

Comment: i did not downvote, but i assume the person who did did so because the fiddle shows alternating red and green, not every row red AND green.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest method:

```
$("tr").addClass("red");
```